# Is aluminium(III) oxide (Al2O3) diamagnetic or paramagnetic? ("wrong" magnetic properties of aluminum foil)

Tags: electromagnetism

The question is pretty much in the title. I've tried to google this but failed for the moment being.

I've tried to use a piece of aluminum foil as a torsion pendulum and hanged it below a stransparent plastic cup and put a strong magnet nearby. I expected it to get turned into the field like a bulk piece [here](https://youtu.be/u36QpPvEh2c?t=2m53s) but to my surprise it acts like a diamagnetic instead (turns out of the field). I wonder if surface aluminium oxide can cause this...

If you have any other hypotheses that explain this "failed" experiment, feel free to propose them.

Comment: Foil is not pure aluminum. Try to demagnetize it. The best demagnetizer is Han-D-Mag by Annis.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminium is paramagnetic and so an external magnetic field produced by a magnet would magnetise the aluminium such that the aluminium is attracted to the magnet.
However, even if the magnet field was a very strong one produced by a neodymium magnet, that force of attraction would be very small and you would have to set up the apparatus carefully to show the attraction.

What you probably have observed is the result of induced current produced in the aluminium which is in the presence of a changing magnet field produced by the movement of the magnet?
As the magnet approached the aluminium the magnetic field experienced by the aluminium would have increased and the aluminium would have reacted by trying to move into a region where the change of magnet field was smaller - further from the magnet.
This is Lena’s law in action where the induced current is in such a direction as to try and oppose the motion (changing magnetic field producing it).
So there is a force of repulsion between the magnet and the aluminium whilst they are moving towards one another.

If this is the reason for the effect that you have observed then you should observe a force of attraction as the magnet moves away from the aluminium. Do you?

**Update** after spotting [the link to a video in the question](https://youtu.be/u36QpPvEh2c?t=2m53s).

Note how the suspended aluminium tube first orientates itself perpendicular to the magnetic field as the magnet is moved closer to the aluminium tube (the aluminium tube is trying to move into a region where the (change in ) magnetic field is smaller and then once the magnet stops moving the aluminium tube orientates itself parallel to the static magnet field showing aluminium to be paramagnetic.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of Foucault currents and the corresponding interaction and I was careful about moving the magnet slowly, but I'll think more about this and try to design the experiment better to distinguish this. Offhand, I'd say that this actually works in an opposite direction: when I move the magnet around the cup relatively rapidly, aluminum follows it (to maintain the magnetic flow) but when  I put it nearby really slowly, the aluminum gets repelled. I have to admit though, that the effect wasn't 100% reproducible so I have to tinker with it further.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try moving the magnet away rapidly, that may be a nice addition to the current observations.

Comment: @YakovL Have you noticed the effect I have described in the video?

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure that it's because of the magnet but not due to torsion of the string or some air flows? It rotates towards the perpendicular direction when the magnet is way too far so I don't think it has to do with magnet field at all (I'm dealing with similar magnets so I don't believe they can affect aluminum on such a distance).

Comment: By the way, when I repeated my setup I've failed to reproduce any effects aside aluminum foil following the magnet when I move it (which totally agrees with the Foucault current/their field theory) but probably I had something different about distances and will report back if I get some more observations.